# Flutter Notification dont show

Tags: flutter, dart, android-notifications, flutter-notification

I have a problem with notifications that are not displayed. I am trying to get a notification within a certain time, but I have no idea what I am doing wrong.There are no errors or interrupts, the application is working properly, but the messages are not displayed.When I use instant notifications, they appear.

```
    class TaskWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Task task;
  final DateTime selectedDate;
  TaskWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.task,
    required this.selectedDate,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TaskWidget> createState() => _TaskWidgetState();
}

class _TaskWidgetState extends State<TaskWidget> {
  var notifyHelper;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    notifyHelper = NotifyHelper();
    notifyHelper.initializeNotification();
    notifyHelper.requestIOSPermissions();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => buildTask(context);

  Widget buildTask(BuildContext context) => _buildTask(context);

  Widget _buildTask(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.task.date == DateFormat.yMd().format(widget.selectedDate)) {
      DateTime date = DateFormat.Hm().parse(widget.task.startTime.toString());
      var myTime = DateFormat("HH:mm").format(date);
      //print(myTime);
      notifyHelper.scheduledNotification(
          int.parse(myTime.toString().split(":")[0]),
          int.parse(myTime.toString().split(":")[1]),
          widget.task);
  return GestureDetector();
} else {
  return Container();
}
;
```

}

and this is notifyHelper class:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_timezone/flutter_native_timezone.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

import '../model/task.dart';

class NotifyHelper {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin(); //

  initializeNotification() async {
    _configureLocalTimezone();
    final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        IOSInitializationSettings(
            requestBadgePermission: false,
            requestAlertPermission: false,
            onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
    final AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings("appicon");

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: selectNotification);
  }

  Future onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
      int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {
    Get.dialog(Text("test"));
  }

  void requestIOSPermissions() {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestPermissions(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true,
        );
  }

  displayNotification() async {
    print("doing test");
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your channel id', 'your channel name',
        importance: Importance.max, priority: Priority.high);
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
        android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
        iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      "title",
      "body",
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'It could be anything you pass',
    );
  }

  scheduledNotification(int hour, int minutes, Task task) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        0,
        task.title,
        task.note,
        _convertTime(hour, minutes).add(const Duration(seconds: 2)),
        //tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
        const NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'your channel id',
          'your channel name',
        )),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time);
  }

  

  tz.TZDateTime _convertTime(int hour, int minutes) {
    final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    tz.TZDateTime scheduleDate = tz.TZDateTime(
      tz.local,
      now.year,
      now.month,
      now.day,
      hour,
      minutes,
    );
    if (scheduleDate.isBefore(now)) {
      scheduleDate = scheduleDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
    }

    return scheduleDate;
  }

  Future<void> _configureLocalTimezone() async {
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    final String timeZone = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
    tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZone));
  }

  Future selectNotification(String? payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      print('notification payload: $payload');
    } else {
      print("Notification Done");
    }
    Get.to(() => Container());
  }
}
```

Help please. :(

Answer (score 0):

im guessing you following this code from dbestech yt video, i had the same problem but i manage to fix it by changing the channel name and id in

```
 android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'your channel id',
          'your channel name',
        )),
```

and

```
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your channel id', 'your channel name',
```

change it to whatever you like,
for ex:

```
 android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'task_reminder',
          'taskapp',
        )),
```

```
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'task_reminder', 'taskapp',
```

hope this helps